# In search of an idiom

Tags: idiom-requests

In my native language we have an idiom that goes like "to check/sync own's watch". It means, to verify with yourself that you are on the same page with something. To make sure you know the latest tendencies and are following them.

### Example:

> I go to interviews "to check/sync my watch" with the current status of the IT business.

Meaning: I go to interviews to make sure my knowledge and salary are matching what currently the companies are looking for.

Now, what's the corresponding idiom, if any, in English? Thanks.

Comment: To *keep in touch* with the wider business?

Comment: Also "to stay/keep abreast of" and "to stay/be up to speed with" http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stay+abreast+of http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/up+to+speed

Comment: erm you said one yourself - "get on the right / same page"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A comparable idiomatic expression would be ***keep up (with)***.

> I go to interviews to ***keep up*** with the current status of the IT
> business.

Cambridge Dictionary:

> **[keep up (with sb/sth)](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/keep-up-with-sb-sth)**
> *— phrasal verb with keep; kept* ​
>
> to do whatever is necessary to stay level or equal with someone or something:
>
> Technology changes so fast, it's hard to ***keep up** with* it.

Answer (score 9):

> ***have/keep your finger on the pulse*** ​
>
> to be/stay familiar with the most recent changes or improvements:
> *The situation changes daily, so you need to keep your finger on the pulse.*

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-keep-your-finger-on-the-pulse

> *A magazine editor has to have her finger on the pulse of fashion.*

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/have-your-finger-on-the-pulse

Comment: I think this is a more apt idiom than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Consider one of the following:

- to stay/keep/be up to date with
- to keep/stay abreast of
- to be on top of
- to keep track of
- to be/keep in touch with

Comment: I think **stay up to date** [with] is the best all-purpose equivalent.  Sometimes it's good to **do a reality check**.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible colloquialism:

- **to have one's ear to the ground**

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ear-to-the-ground--have-one-s):

> Also, **keep one's ear to the ground**.
>
> Be or remain well informed; be on the watch for new trends and information. For example, *"She knew she'd succeed as a reporter if she kept her ear to the ground."*
>
> This graphic expression probably alludes to listening for distant hoofbeats by putting one's ear close to the ground. [Late 1800s ]

Answer (score -1):

You could say you want to [**refamiliarize**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refamiliarise) yourself.

> To familiarise with something one previously was familiar with.

It's debatable whether this is a "real" word, but any English speaker will know exactly what you mean.

> I go to interviews to **refamiliarize myself** with the current status of the IT business.

You could also consider some of the synonyms to [familiarize](https://www.google.com/webhp?ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=define:+familiarize):

> make conversant with, make familiar with, acquaint with; accustom to, habituate to, instruct in, teach in, educate in, school in, prime in, introduce to; brief in/about; *informal* put in the picture about/with, give the lowdown on, fill in on, get up to speed on/with

Also note the difference between American (*-ize*) and British (*-ise*) spelling.